# Scala has smart compiler?

Tags: exception, scala

I made recursive function, just like

```
require : L (List[Int])
```

L pattern matching

1. `Nil => Thread.dumpStack()`
2. `x :: xs => print(x) + function(xs)`

> ```
> def function(L : List[Int]) {
>     L match {
>         case Nil => Thread.dumpStack()
>         case x :: xs => print(x + " "); function(xs)
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> val l = (1 to 5).toList //
>   function(l)

So I think this function in the stack frame n times, but it occurs one time, I think this function has already found `Nil` and print out exception `Thread.dumpStack`.

Is scala compiler smart or other else?

Comment: -1 Please be clearer: provide a short code sample and a REPL transcript to illustrate the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are observing *tail recursion*: there is nothing to store from one iteration to the next, so the recursion is essentially turned into a while loop by the compiler.  (So, yes, the compiler is smart in that way.)

Answer (score 1):

As Rex Kerr pointed out, this is the Scala compiler applying a tail call optimization. If you want to know what is compiled in the end, you can run the compiler with an extra argument:

```
scalac -Xprint:tailcalls yourfile.scala
```

This will print the intermediate representation after the `tailcalls` compiler phase. (If you want to learn about all phases, you can also run `scalac -Xshow-phases`.) For example, on the following input:

```
object TailRec {
  def foo(l : List[Int]) : Unit = l match {
    case Nil => Thread.dumpStack()
    case x :: xs => println(x); foo(xs)
  }
}
```

The compiler will print (for the function `foo`):

```
def foo(l: List[Int]): Unit = {
  <synthetic> val _$this: TailRec.type = TailRec.this;
  _foo(_$this,l){
    l match {
      case immutable.this.Nil => java.this.lang.Thread.dumpStack()
      case (hd: Int, tl: List[Int])collection.immutable.::[Int]((x @ _), (xs @ _)) => {
        scala.this.Predef.println(x);
        _foo(TailRec.this, xs)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The part `_foo(_$this,l)` looks like a function definition, but it's really a label, and the "call" `_foo(TailRec.this, xs)` is in fact a jump to that label. So in short, the compiler rewrote a recursive call into what really is a while loop.

The compiler will apply the optimization automatically when it can. If you want to make sure that a function is properly rewritten, you can annotate it with `@tailrec`, and the compiler will produce an error if it cannot optimize it.